# Is eclipse clearing out extra files from workspace/project/bin?

Tags: eclipse

I'm developing an app using Eclipse IDE under linux. While developing, I'm having terminal opened, testing things under workspace/myApp/bin. For the needs of testing, I copied several files there - one txt file, one gif image. Also, several more files have been created as a result of my app.

However, today I started Eclipse, opened one terminal window and navigated to workspace/myApp/bin, only to see that image, text file and other output files are gone, leaving only .class files belonging to my app.

All my settings are unchanged, so it's a default Eclipse setup. Eclipse is 3.5.2.

It's not so important, but I'd love to know if Eclipse automatically clears those files when closing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse probably is clearing files when you build, and if you have set it up to "Build Automatically" then it can happen anytime when any files change.

But:
You should not be having files in the `bin` (the *output* folder) folder anyway. The required files (images, config files,...) should be in their own "source folders". "Source folders" are automatically copied to the output folder (`bin` in your case).